# Node works globally but not in a specific directory after brew install yarn

Tags: macos, homebrew, node.js

MacOS Mojave here. When I installed `yarn` with `brew install`, I couldn't run `node` (and thus `npm`). I went through a fair amount of troubleshooting steps that essentially forced uninstalled node and removed symlinks to node files in `/usr/bin`. I then installed `nvm` and successfully installed `node`. But, when I run `node -v` in a specific directory that I'm developing in, I get `bash: node: command not found`, even though I can successfully run that command globally. Why can't I access the command in this directory?

Edit: Successfully running `node -v` globally was an isolated success that apparently happened because I had installed `nvm` on that terminal. Once I opened a new terminal window, `node` gave the same "command not found" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimenting, I found a suboptimal solution. Installing `nvm` should place a folder called `.nvm` in the home directory, and this folder contains a script called `nvm.sh`. Running `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` makes the `nvm` installation of `node` available in the immediate terminal. You can then run this command every time you open an interactive bash terminal (different for other shells) by putting `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` at the end of `~/.bash_profile`. The reason this is suboptimal is that this (fairly long) script is run every time you open a terminal, which adds a half second delay on my machine. I'd love to see better answers. Long story short, don't use `brew` for `node` related tasks.